# Mongoose transactions don't rollback when I use an array of promises ( Promise.all )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, transactions

I have a weird situation here
I'm trying to insert some write queries in an array ( All of them belong to the same transaction ), and use Promise.all(arr) to execute/rollback on the transaction as a whole
The thing is, if my code throws an error and I abort transaction before calling Promise.all(), operations to-be-done in the promises array are commited !. However, if my code throws an error after calling Promise.all(), documents are reverted back to their original state as expected.
How to avoid commiting changes to documents even if transaction is aborted just because I throw an exception before calling Promise.all().

Here is the code snipper

```
module.exports.updateVariantStock = async (req, res, next) => {
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();
  try {

    session.startTransaction();

    const opts = { session };

    const { newStock } = req.body;

    const { variant } = req.mydata;

    const promises = [];

    variant.stock = Number(variant.stock) + Number(newStock);

    const variantPromise = variant.save(opts);
    promises.push(variantPromise);

    const stockLogElement = new VariantStockLogElement({
     // Data to insert
    });

    const newStockLogContainerPromise = stockLogElement.save(opts);

    promises.push(newStockLogContainerPromise);

    throw new Error("A test error"); // If error is thrown here, changes are commited
    await Promise.all(promises);
    throw new Error("A test error"); // If error is thrown here, changes are rolled-back

    await session.commitTransaction();
  
    return res.status(200).json({ success: "Stock is updated." });
  } catch (err) {
      await session.abortTransaction();
    next(err);
  } finally {
    session.endSession();
  }
};
```

Notice that if I run any db query ( not related to transaction ) before throwing this error, changes are rolled-back. But I get this error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Transaction with { txnNumber: 1 } has been aborted.
```

I really don't understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Promise.all with transactions in MongoDB, it's important to be aware of the order in which the promises are settled. In your code, when you throw an error before calling Promise.all(promises), the promises in the array may already start to execute, and MongoDB may see these changes as individual operations outside the transaction. However, if an error is thrown after calling Promise.all(promises), the operations are bundled into the same transaction. To ensure that the promises inside the array are not executed until the Promise.all is called, you can move the line throw new Error("A test error") to after Promise.all(promises). You can consider doing something like this,

```js
// Execute promises within the transaction
const promiseResult = await Promise.all(promises);

// Check if any promise rejected
const hasRejectedPromise = promiseResult.some(p => p instanceof Error || p instanceof mongoose.Error);

if (hasRejectedPromise) {
      throw new Error("A test error"); // If error is thrown here, changes are rolled-back
}

await session.commitTransaction();
```

But if for some reason your goal is to abort the transaction as soon as a single promise throws an error, you can achieve this by removing the Promise.all and handling each promise individually with a try...catch block. If any promise throws an error, you can immediately abort the transaction and handle the error. Consider something like this,

```js
    variant.stock = Number(variant.stock) + Number(newStock);
    const variantPromise = variant.save(opts);

    try {
      await variantPromise; // Handle the promise individually
    } catch (error) {
      // If an error occurs, immediately abort the transaction
      await session.abortTransaction();
      throw error;
    }

    const stockLogElement = new VariantStockLogElement({
      // Data to insert
    });

    const newStockLogContainerPromise = stockLogElement.save(opts);

    try {
      await newStockLogContainerPromise; // Handle the promise individually
    } catch (error) {
      // If an error occurs, immediately abort the transaction
      await session.abortTransaction();
      throw error;
    }

    await session.commitTransaction();
    // .... Continue with the rest of your code ...
```

Comment: The thing is I'm simulating what might happen if my code throws a runtime error before calling Promise.all().
I wouldn't throw any errors, I'm just trying to figure out a way to roll-back in case some error occurs before starting to execute db opeartions.

Comment: "a way to roll-back in case some error occurs before starting to execute db operations"- what is there to roll back in that case?! Obviously try block will pick up the error and catch will handle it. "I really don't understand what is happening here." - I was under the impression that was the question. And i believe first part of my answer explains it and then proposes some approaches. Edge cases simulation effort is apparent too. Feedback on how I can improve my answer to properly address your question will be appreciated.

Comment: You are right, nothing to roll back.
I accepted your answer and marked it as useful, thanks a lot.
Do you have any idea how can I prevent db operations from executing if I throw error before Promise.all() ? Sometimes you can't just exceute operations individually.
Say you have a for loop, each loop constructs a promise, I don't think executing a db operation per loop is acceptable, so what would the solution to such a situation be ?

Comment: For simulating, you don't randomly throw an error before promise.all() but rather before 'the promise construction' logic. You can also 'reject' an individual promise within a loop to observe the effect it has on promise.all(). [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622331/why-is-my-array-of-promises-running-before-calling-promise-all) a link, please read through all the answers and comments to gain a better understanding of the relationship between async operations and promise.all()

Comment: The throw new Error() statement will be executed synchronously when encountered in the code. If you place the throw new Error() after the promise construction and before Promise.all(), the error will interrupt the synchronous flow of your code. Still, it won't prevent any asynchronous operations that might have been initiated within the 'promise construction logic' from completing. In your case thrown error is being captured by the try block and immediately transaction is being aborted, while some async operations continue to run in the background and completes outside the transaction.